# pandas dataframe str to datetime with format as 5:30PM

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to convert a dataframe column from str to datetime format with pd.to_datetime.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Event Number' : [1, 2, 3] ,
        'Time': ['1PM', '2PM', '5:30PM'] }
df = pd.DataFrame (data)
pd.to_datetime(df['Time', format = '%I%p']
```

however, I got an error message: time data '5:30PM' does not match format '%I%p' (match)

Answer (score 0):

You can just let Pandas guess:

```
pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 ' + df['Time'])
```

Output:

```
0   2021-01-01 13:00:00
1   2021-01-01 14:00:00
2   2021-01-01 17:30:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: never thought pandas is so smart. But you are smarter than python. Thanks so much. It works.